# Network Request fail on basic auth with fetch in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch, base64, basic-authentication

My code look like this

```
import base64 from "react-native-base64";

  fetch("https:apilink", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Basic " + base64.encode("xelsysadm:Secure99"),
      },
    })
```

but still I dont know why it showing network req fail It working fine on postamn . Is i am doing something worng. please guide me.

Comment: Once try with http it work or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put

> Authorization

into quotation marks, like that :

```js
import base64 from "react-native-base64";

  fetch("https:apilink", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Basic " + base64.encode("xelsysadm:Secure99"),
      },
    })
```